# ERROR: [050]: unable to acquire lock on file '/tmp/pgbackrest/demo-archive.lock': Permission denied

Tags: postgresql-11, pgbackrest

I have been trying to load data incrementally in postgres on linux(ubuntu) from the source (https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/pgbackrest/2.00/pdf/backrest.pdf) while I am trying to create a stanza I am getting the following error.

As I am new to the Linux platform it has been taken more then 2 days and I couldn't solve it!

```
sudo -u postgres pgbackrest --stanza=demo --log-level-console=info stanza-create
2019-10-03 16:16:22.730 P00   INFO: stanza-create command begin 2.16: --log-level-console=info --pg1-path=/var/lib/postgresql/11/demo --repo1-path=/var/lib/pgbackrest --stanza=demo

ERROR: [050]: unable to acquire lock on file '/tmp/pgbackrest/demo-archive.lock': Permission denied
       HINT: does the user running pgBackRest have permissions on the '/tmp/pgbackrest/demo-archive.lock' file?
2019-10-03 16:16:22.730 P00   INFO: stanza-create command end: aborted with exception [050]

ERROR: [050]: unable to acquire lock on file '/tmp/pgbackrest/demo-archive.lock': Permission denied
       HINT: does the user running pgBackRest have permissions on the '/tmp/pgbackrest/demo-archive.lock' file?
2019-10-03 16:16:22.730 P00   INFO: stanza-create command end: aborted with exception [050]
```

What is the reason why this is showing and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue and solved by just deleting the temp folder and its files

```
sudo rm -r pgbackrest/
```

It worked for me.
Another possible solution is to delete the temp folder and stanza & re-create the stanza.